# Can I get data from one SQL database and then post that data on another SQL database on a diferent server using MVC C#

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller

I searched endlessly and couldn't find a answer to my problem,

I'm building an MVC project where I need to get data from some tables in an SQL database, display them (no problem in this section) and then is there a way to post that information on another database hosted on a diferent server with identical tables?

The data I want to post is a new record

Thanks for your time ! :)

Comment: You searched endlessly? It's more a matter of just doing it. Make an attempt. If your attempt doesn't work, create a [MCVE] and clearly explain which part you're stuck on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use two different database connections:

```
var con1 = new MySqlConnection("server="+host1+";database="+dbname+";uid="+user+";pwd="+pass+";");
con1.Open();
var cmd1 = new MySqlCommand( "SELECT name FROM mytable ", con1 );
var reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

var con2 = new MySqlConnection("server="+host2+";database="+dbname+";uid="+user+";pwd="+pass+";");
con2.Open();

while( reader.Read() )
{
    var name = reader.GetString( 0 );
    var cmd2 = new MySqlCommand( "INSERT INTO mytable ( name ) VALUES ("+name+")", con2 );
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

for better performance, use bulk inserts.